# Where I can share/buy/sell SharePoint solutions

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, solution-package

Is the some area/community/marketplace for SharePoint solutions where I can upload/download ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bit offtopic but there are a few markets you can place your code on.

**Office Store (Office/SharePoint add-ins)**

https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/submit-to-the-office-store

> The Office Store provides a convenient location for you to upload new
>   Office Add-ins, SharePoint Add-ins, Office 365 web apps, and Power BI
>   custom visuals that are aimed both at consumers and businesses. To
>   include your solution in the Office Store, you submit it to the Seller
>   Dashboard. You will need to create an individual or company account
>   and, if applicable, add payout information.

**Alternative Markets**

There are many online markets that you can help you sell your digital products, as they have a huge amount of users. [Envato's CodeCanyon](https://codecanyon.net) is one of them. Although quite generic, you can use to sell a WSP for example. I'm sure there are many others.

**Communities**

[TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/) can be an example of a place to store your code while helping others.

Another way is going open source and using [GitHub](https://github.com/) for example.

Comment: You can also still search Codeplex even though no new things are going there. (Codeplex is closed to new projects and they suggest GitHub.)